# Derive dialog class from custom type when using class wizard to link dialog template and class?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I've a dialog template created in VC++ 2013 resource editor. I'd like to use automatic code generation (for event handlers, DDX, etc) and I think I need to get VS to create the class for me to do this easily - but double-clicking on the dialog the wizard only lets me select from standard base classes, and we have our own dialog base class which derives from `CDialog`.

How should I proceed?

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about writing a custom wizard?

Comment: @rrirower I didn't even know I could! I'm not sure that's a route we'd want to go though.

Comment: Keep it as an option since a [custom wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhceedxx(v=vs.120).aspx) will allow you to create code templates and snippets that you can incorporate into your project.

Comment: "The Visual C++ Custom Wizard is the tool to use when you need to create a new custom wizard. The easiest way to create a custom wizard is to use the Custom Wizard." - wow, epic documentation ;)

Comment: @Mr.Boy: The documentation uses casing to convey information. In this case *"custom wizard"* refers to the new wizard you are about to create, and *"Custom Wizard"* to the *"Visual C++ Custom Wizard"*, the tool to use for the job. What wording would you propose that's more epic or less epic, whichever you would regard as better?